# Looking for ways to improve speed of boost graph for Astar path finding algorithm

Tags: c++, boost-graph

So I have graph that is acquired based on topology of a 3D environment.
The graph is defined as;

```
struct VertexProperty
{
  std::uint32_t label;
  std::string name;
};

typedef float Cost;

// specify some types
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::setS,            // edge
    boost::vecS,            // vertex
    boost::undirectedS,     // type
    VertexProperty,         // vertex property
    boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, Cost>> // edge property
  GraphT;
```

I fill this graph by iterating through an adjacency_list which was again from the topology of 3D Environment I have, think this as a simulated area.

```
  boost::tie(e, edge_added) = boost::add_edge(u, v, g);
```

this was I add all edges. Up-to this point everything is reasonably fast.
Now after I have constructed the graph I run AStar and it takes around 11 sec to process a graph with approximately 730 vertices and 1873 edges. To me this seems a little too much because the graph is not huge. I was wondering what could be taking so long for A* on this graph ?.
I use a euclidean heuristic and classic goal_visitor just as boost-astar-cities [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/example/astar-cities.cpp). Note that my code includes quite a lot of unrelevant pieces so it wont make much sense to add all of it.

Here is how I call the A*

```
try {
      auto heuristic =
        distance_heuristic<GraphT, Cost, SuperVoxelClusters *>(
        &supervoxel_clusters_, goal_vertex, g);
      auto c_visitor = custom_goal_visitor<vertex_descriptor>(goal_vertex);

        boost::astar_search_tree(
          g, start_vertex, heuristic,
        boost::predecessor_map(&p[0]).distance_map(&d[0]).visitor(c_visitor));
      

      // A path was NOT found. Warn user about it
      RCLCPP_WARN(logger_, "%s search failed to find a valid path!", graph_search_method_.c_str());
    } catch (FoundGoal found_goal) {
      // Found a path to the goal, catch the exception
      // Handle the path ...
     }
```

I do find a path if one exists but the problem is performance. Refer to the picture where I visualize the constructed graph and path. Also be noted that the path has some post-processing(interpolation and smoothing) so it does not exactly looks as expected.

Is there anything that would get my speed up to reasonable levels ?

[image]

Comment: Can you add metrics how many nodes are visited? Does the profiler reveal a hotspot (like maybe your heurstics function?)

Comment: Hi @sehe, So I get a track of visited nodes for a sample run, for instance it visits a total of 28 nodes out of 727 nodes. Which I would say indicates that heuristic is doing what its supposed to do ? Unfortunately I did not get what exactly you mean when you say profiler revelation, Could you elaborate more on that ?

Comment: as a side note, I also tried out dijsktra which doesn't make use of heuristic function. The behavior is very similar, the performance is not desirable.

Comment: Yeah, this is not making much sense. The heuristic may be doing what it is supposed to do (in terms of algorithmic complexity) but the logical conclusion is that evaluations of the heuristics function takes 11s/28 ≈ almost 400ms per node. That's a very high cost. Any operation taking in the order of seconds will result in very poor performance when it is executed repeatedly. Profiling the code should show this as the bottleneck?

Comment: Thanks a lot @sehe. Turns out that I was not bench-marking the code accurately. The huge overhead was actually coming from post processing jobs(interpolation and smoothing). I have tuned them and now I can achieve desirable speed. Just for reference, Now a graph with 2878 vertices and 7375 edges takes a mere time of 17.6 ms for a A* to return a path. A total of 60 vertices are visited until a goal is found. This is far better than I hoped for :).

Comment: Sounds good, assuming the outcome is correct :) Good job